# How to run Node.js and MongoDB interactive shell simultaneously within a Docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-15.04

I have a **Docker** image configured with **node.js** (with express) and **mongoDB**. 
I run the `mongod` service in the background:  `mongod --fork --logpath /var/lib/mongodb.log`. I start my node.js app: `npm start` which results in an interactive shell(shows the requests to server).

But if I want to monitor the DB changes being made by my node.js application, each time I am forced to stop the node server (ctrl + c) and launches the mongoDB interactive shell using: `mongo`.

So the next time if I want to run my node.js app, I had to stop the mongoDB interactive shell (ctrl + c) and run the server all over again.

Is there any way to run both `node.js interactive shell` and `mongoDB interactive shell` simultaneously, may be in two different terminal window in `Docker` ?

The image below shows the snapshot of my terminal.[image]

I am using **Ubuntu 15.04** and **Docker version 1.5.0**, build a8a31ef

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not running these services in the same container. Run each one in a separate container and use `docker-compose` to manage building and running the containers.

`docker-compose logs` will show you the output of each service.

Managing the services in separate containers will let you modify each independently, and gives you an environment that is closer to a production setup.

Comment: My initial idea was to run each service in a separate container. But couldn't link the containers to each other. My node app running in CONTAINER1 was not able to communicate with the mongoDb running in CONTAINER2.

Could you please suggest a way to achieve this ?

Comment: This is the recommended approach. If your interested, look for questions related to 'docker-compose' and running multiple containers in unison. If you still can't find an answer, consider re-wording your question or opening a new one

Comment: Yes, if you google something like "docker-compose node mongo" you should find a bunch of examples

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you try installing [`tmux`](https://tmux.github.io/). You can add the following to your Dockerfile to make `tmux` available in the container:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tmux
```

`tmux` will provide you with a screen that can represent multiple windows with multiple panes, handling the I/O for you.

Alternatively, you can use `CTRL+Z`, `fg`, `bg`, to change the process your viewing in the [foreground](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/unix-background-job/). A final solution might be to run `docker exec` in two separate terminals.

Lastly, not exactly related to your question, you could expose the port to  `mongod` to your host and connect to it via your local `mongo` CLI client or a GUI client such as [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/).

Comment: "docker exec"  is the one I was looking for.

Comment: But if we could achieve @dnephin idea of running each service in a separate containers and linking them together, that would be the best and recommended solution (see my comment for dnephin's answer).